# Why doesn't "/documentclass{article}" work (forward slash vs. backslash)

Tags: errors

I am new to LaTex. I am reading the book "Latex" by Stefan Kottwitz, but under "creating our first document" I was supposed to write the following:

```
/documentclass{article}
/begin{document}
This is our firstdocument.
/end{document}
```

When I write this in Texworks, I only get this message in the console output:

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>
> l.1 /
>      documentclass{article}
> ? 
> Process interrupted by user
> ```

Does anyone know what I have to do in order to make it work?

Comment: Welcome! Backslash (\\) and forward slash (/) are not the same character. The code you posted is using forward slash when LaTeX expects a backslash for control sequences.

Comment: Try: 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is our firstdocument.
\end{document}

Comment: What you said worked perfectly Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a typo in the code (misread documentation).

Comment: @PaulGessler Undoubtedly other users will make the same mistake. I think you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: @yo' I don't think the question should be closed, just answered simply. It's surely a common error and we might as well have an answer for it. I edited the question with this in mind.

Comment: @AndrewCashner However, the question is unsearchable. Once you know that you used a forward slash, you know it's a typo. IMHO it can't serve anything.

Comment: @yo' It's not off topic, and it's not just a typo, it's a misunderstanding of how to type basic TeX commands (which ultimately comes down to how catcodes are defined), and that is very much within the scope of TeX. I'm fine with closing it but leaving the answer.

Comment: You could download all LaTeX code examples from the publisher's book website [here](http://link.packtpub.com/lOKssB) , so there won't be any typing mistake.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz For some things, it's better to tap it out yourself :-) Having the auxiliary materials is good, but OP will never make this mistake again :-)

Answer (score 6):

Backslash (`\`) and forward slash (`/`) are not the same character.

The code you posted is using forward slash when LaTeX expects a backslash for control sequences.

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
> ```

is the error given here because the first thing encountered in the input is text (`/`), which is not allowed outside the `document` environment. You can see this further along in the error message:

> ```
> l.1 /
>      documentclass{article}
> ?
> ```

The line breaks in the error message where the error is encountered, which is at the forward slash (`/`).

To correct the code, use backslashes (`\`) for all control sequences (commands/macros/etc.):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
This is our first document.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the question ends up being closed, I will transfer any rep earned here to bounties. (But I won't make animated GIFs to tell you that. `:-)`)